# Window does not appear when I load .py program (Jython, Beginner)

Tags: java, python, swing, jython

I am creating a simple chat GUI.  The following code loads without errors, but I cannot figure out how to make the window appear so that I can actually *see* that it is working.  Before using classes it would show up automatically (e.g. running a simple "Hello, world!" application).  Do I need to use the command line?

Thanks for any help--I am new to this.

```
import javax.swing as swing

import java.awt as awt

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent

import java.awt.event.ActionListener

class Login:

  def __init__(self):

    self.login = Login
    self.chatRoom = ChatRoom(self.login)

    self.loginMain = swing.JFrame("Welcome to J-Chat!")
    self.loginMain.contentPane.layout = awt.BorderLayout()
    self.loginMain.preferredSize = (300, 120)    
    self.loginMain.setLocationRelativeTo(null)
    self.loginMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)

    self.loginLabel = swing.JLabel("User Name: ")
    self.loginMain.contentPane.add(loginLabel)

    self.loginField = swing.JTextField(20)
    self.loginMain.contentPane.add(loginField)

    self.loginButton = swing.JButton("Login")
    self.loginMain.contentPane.add(loginButton)
    self.loginButton.actionPerformed = self.buttonClick

    self.mainWin.pack()
    self.mainWin.show()

  def buttonClick(self, event):

    self.chatRoom = ChatRoom.chatRoomMain(self.chatRoom, self.loginField.text)
```

Comment: You seem to have `self.loginMain` and `self.mainWin`. I presume the latter is an accident.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually run the class in order to use it.

At the bottom of your file, try adding the following lines:

```
login = Login()
```

That should instantiate and execute the `Login` class.

---

A more idiomatic way would be to wrap the instantiation in an `if` block:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    login = Login()
```

This will make Python instantiate the `Login` class only if you directly run the file from the command line, and will avoid instantiating it if you're simply importing your file. This is useful if you want to test a given file to make sure it works, but still be able to import it and reuse it elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to type python.exe on start search and open properties and copy and paste the location right click on your py program then clikc open whithc and chosse/chosse default and paste the location and click on python or python.exe